# django class based CreateApiView author_id is not null?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have also authenticate it with token but when I create a new post error is alert `IntegrityError at /api/create/ NOT NULL constraint failed: core_article.author_id` how can I valid data with request user in serializer?

model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Article(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Short title")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from core.models import Article


class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field=User.USERNAME_FIELD, read_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'author',
            'title',
            'content',
            'status',
        ]
```

views.py

```
class ArticleCreate(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.status_objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
```

Comment: Set `required=True` and make it read/write? How else can you specify the `author`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but you can pass the user as author object to your serializer and in your serializer use that author to create your `Article` object (Note: I assume that you have used correct `authentication_class` in your view and have access to user from your request object).

First you need to override the perform create of your view:

```
class ArticleCreate(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.status_objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Which will send an user instance to your serializer validated data. Then you should change your serializer to:

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'content',
            'status',
        ]
```

Note that the line `author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field=User.USERNAME_FIELD, read_only=True, required=False)` and `author` are removed from your serializer. But if you need to serialize the id of that author (read only purpose) you can change your serializer to:

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'author',
            'content',
            'status',
        ]
        read_only_fields = ('author',)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field=User.USERNAME_FIELD, read_only=True,required=True)
```

Please change `required=False`  to `required=True` . If you set True then don't add Null value. So you avoid this errror.